# Is it possible to have something similar to multiline equation inside a table row?

Tags: tables

I need to build some sort of table with a series of equations from different papers, and I am having an hard time with formatting the table

I got something like this:
[image]

I wanted to know if there was any way to have the equal after the G get closer to the left side of the last equation in the Model column, and also if there was any way to set the overall width of my table to equal the width of my text.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Author  &Reactions  &Model\\
        \hline
        Voltz et al & \begin{tabular}{c}
                                                    \ce{CO + 0.5 O2 -> CO2} \\
                                                    \ce{C3H6 + 4.5 O2 -> 3 CO2 + 3 H2O} 
                                                \end{tabular}   
                                                &\begin{tabular}{c}
                                                    $r_1 =  \frac{k_1 \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} \cdot C_{\ce{O2}}}{G} $    \\
                                                    $r_2 =  \frac{k_2 \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \cdot C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}$ \\
                                                    {\small$\begin{array}{rl} \renewcommand*{\tabcolsep{0pt}}
                                                    G = &\left(1 + k_{a1} \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} + k_{a2} \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \right) \\
                                                    &\cdot \left(1 + k_{a3} \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \right) \cdot \left(1 + k_{a4} \cdot C_{\ce{NO}} \right) 
                                                    \end{array}$}
                                                \end{tabular}   \\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of `mathtools` you can easy obtain:
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tabular}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
Author  &   Reactions   &    Model\\
    \hline
Voltz et al 
        &   $\begin{gathered}
XXXXXX\\%    \ce{CO + 0.5 O2 -> CO2} \\
YYYYYY\\%    \ce{C3H6 + 4.5 O2 -> 3 CO2 + 3 H2O}
            \end{gathered}$
                        &   $\begin{gathered}
        r_1 =  \frac{k_1 \cdot C_{WWW} \cdot C_{WWW}}{G}   \\
        r_2 =  \frac{k_2 \cdot C_{WWW} \cdot C_{WWW}}{G}  \\
        G = \left(1 + k_{a1}\cdot C_{WW} + k_{a2}
                            \cdot C_{WW} \right)\cdot        \\
            \left(1 + k_{a3}\cdot C_{WW} \cdot C_{WW}\right)\
                            \cdot \left(1 + k_{a4} \cdot C_{WWW} \right)
                             \end{gathered}$                        \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Since I'm not familiar with any  chem related package, I replace `\ce{....}` function with letters W.

**Edit:**
Nicer result and simpler code is possible to obtain with `mdwtab` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,mdwtab}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tabular}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|Mc|Mc|}
    \hlx{hv}
Author  &   \text{Reactions}    &   \text{Model}                    \\
    \hlx{vhv}
Voltz et al 
        &   \begin{gathered}
\ce{CO + 0.5 O2 -> CO2} \\
\ce{C3H6 + 4.5 O2 -> 3 CO2 + 3 H2O}
            \end{gathered}
                        &   \begin{gathered}
        r_1 =  \frac{k_1{\cdot}C_{\ce{CO2}}{\cdot}C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}   \\
        r_2 =  \frac{k_2{\cdot}C_{\ce{C3H6}}{\cdot}C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}  \\
        G = \begin{multlined}[t]
            \left(1 + k_{a1}{\cdot}C_{\ce{CO2}} + k_{a2}
                            {\cdot}C_{\ce{C3H6}} \right){\cdot}     \\[-2ex]
            \left(1 + k_{a3}{\cdot}C_{\ce{CO2}}{\cdot}C_{\ce{C3H6}}\right)
                            {\cdot}\left(1 + k_{a4}{\cdot}C_{\ce{NO}}\right)
            \end{multlined}
                             \end{gathered}                 \\
    \hlx{vh}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):**
Meanwhile I succeed to convince my MikTeX installation to upgrade chem packages, so I'm now able to correct equations -- replace the `WWW` with correct chem formulas. I also improve last equation in third column. This change I do only in second possibilities, but they are applicable in the firs too.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked just fine =). Can I just ask if I have a multicolumn inside my table how can I do to have the same height has the one from tabular enviroment? Because after and \hlx{vh} I get a bit of white space if after I have a multicolumn.

Comment: I suspect that I correctly understand you. Options `v` in \hlx{h}` add some vertical space between horizontal line and cells content. You can put more `v` in option, if you like to have more vertical space. Regarding `\multicolumn` cells: It should behaving the same as in tabular with tiny differences: vertical lines doesn't end at horizontal lines above and below of multi column cell, but intrude a while in it (for amount determined with `v`. This is features of `\hlx` lines. Of course, you can use ordinary \hline instead `\hlx`, but then the control on vertical spaces in rows is lost.

Comment: Ok my usual problem is that I do not know hwo to compensate the height intruded with hlx{hv} with the multicolumn.  For example for something like this: \hlx{hv}  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\ce{CO}}   & 2.72  I get a bit of white space between my horizontal line and my line from multicolumn

Comment: Hm, why you need `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\ce{...}}` ? what special is in this cell that you need it? I guessing that you can simpli write content in cell without use `multicolumn` spanned only one cell.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* have a multiline equation. I propose two variants, using `mathtools`, `cellspace`, `sansmath` and, for one of them, `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, sansmath}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\sansmath\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|Sc|}%>{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}
  \hline
  Author &Reactions &Model\\
  \hline
  Voltz et al. &$ \begin{aligned}%{c}
  \ce{CO + 0.5 O2 & -> CO2} \\[0.5ex]
  \ce{C3H6 + 4.5 O2 & -> 3 CO2 + 3 H2O}
  \end{aligned} $
  & $ \begin{alignedat}{2}
  r_1 & = \mathrlap{\frac{k_1 \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} \cdot C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}}& \\[0.5ex]
  r_2 & = \mathrlap{\frac{k_2 \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \cdot C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}}& \\[0.5ex]
  G & =(1 & & + k_{a1} \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} + k_{a2} \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}})\cdot{} \\[-1ex]
    & & & \overset{\phantom{\textstyle+}} \cdot\left(1 + k_{a3} \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \right) \cdot \left(1 + k_{a4} \cdot C_{\ce{NO}} \right)
  \end{alignedat} $ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\vskip1cm\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ccSc}%>{\arraybackslash}p{8cm}
  \toprule
  Author &Reactions &Model\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
  Voltz et al. &$ \begin{aligned}
  \ce{CO + 0.5 O2 & -> CO2} \\[0.5ex]
  \ce{C3H6 + 4.5 O2 & -> 3 CO2 + 3 H2O}
  \end{aligned} $
  & $ \begin{alignedat}{2}
  r_1 & = \mathrlap{\frac{k_1 \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} \cdot C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}}& \\[0.5ex]
  r_2 & = \mathrlap{\frac{k_2 \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \cdot C_{\ce{O2}}}{G}}& \\[0.5ex]
  G & =(1 & & + k_{a1} \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} + k_{a2} \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}})\cdot{} \\[-1ex]
    & & & \overset{\phantom{\textstyle+}} \cdot\left(1 + k_{a3} \cdot C_{\ce{CO2}} \cdot C_{\ce{C3H6}} \right) \cdot \left(1 + k_{a4} \cdot C_{\ce{NO}} \right)
  \end{alignedat} $ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]